# Approximating an indecomposable distribution by a sequence of decomposable distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X \sim B(p)$, $p=1/2$, a Bernoulli distribution: $\mathbb{P}[X = 1 ]= p = 1 - \mathbb{P}[X = 0 ]$.

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables such that:
$$X_n = X_n^1 + X_n^2\, ,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$
where $X_n^1$ and  $X_n^2$ are non degenerate and independent for all $n$. Suposse that $X_n \sim P_n$ and $X_n^j$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that:
$$P_n \nRightarrow P_X \sim B(p)$$
where $\Rightarrow$ denotes the weak convergence and $P_X$ is the probability induced by $X$.

Intuition for me is easy to understand since $X$ is indecomposable, but I want to show this in a more rigorous way because I want to generalize this result.

My first attempt was to use the [Portmanteau Lemma](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/weak-convergence-and-the-portmanteau-lemma/). Acording this, it is suficient to show that there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$F_n(x)= \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X_n^1 + X_n^2 \leq x) \nrightarrow \mathbb{P}(X\leq x) = F(x),\,\, (n \to \infty)$$
Other way is to find $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $P_X(\partial A)=0$ such that:
$$P_n(A)\nrightarrow P_X(A),\,\, (n \to \infty)$$

I'm really having trouble finding such a $x$ or $A$.. This is my first question.

My second question have to do with the generalization of my first question: let $X \in \{0,1,2\}$ with $X\sim (p_0,p_1,p_2)$ with $p_0 + p_1 + p_2 =1$. Now, suposse that
$$X_n = X_n^1 + X_n^2 + X_n^3\, ,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$
then $P_n \nRightarrow P$.

The idea is that if $X$ takes a finite amount of values I can sufficiently increase the amount of sums in $X_n$ so that each random variable $X_n$ takes values that will never be reached by $X$. In fact, I want to try to find a way to generalize the first question further.

I would appreciate it if you would at least help me with the first question

---

**Update**

Related my first question, I think I need some additional assumptions. Suppose that
$$X_n^j= \theta_n^j Z_n^j, \,\, j=1,2, \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$Z_n^j\in \mathbb{R},\,\,E[Z_n^j] = 0,\,\, E[(Z_n^j)^2] = 1, \,\,\ j = 1,2,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$
where $Z_n^1$ and  $Z_n^2$ are non degenerate and independent.
Futhermore, suppose:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{j=1,2}|\theta_n^j|=0$$